# R Upgrade/Installation on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have tried to upgrade my R from 3.4.4 to 3.5 on Xubuntu 16.04. 
I followed this instruction

1. Go to the file: computer/etc/apt/sources.list Other Software Add deb
   http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ <---
   change "-cran35" for the current version according to
   "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/"
2. open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) write on the terminal: `sudo apt-get update` Enter the password of your PC session write on the terminal: 
       sudo apt-get
       install r-base Restart the computer

However, upon `sudo apt-get install r-base`, I get the following error:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  r-base : Depends:
>   r-recommended (= 3.5.1-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed E:
>   Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is this a dependency error? What I have done is I have to make sure the APT-secure key is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by removing the older CRAN deb source: 
http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial